# Is the declined flags warning a bit overzealous?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, declined-flags

I have, on Super User, an about 96% total helpful flags rate (and a [Marshal](https://superuser.com/help/badges/121/marshal?userid=53590) badge). This made me rather curious when I tried to flag a post and the UI indicated that flags had been declined and I should review them before flagging further, so I went to look.

Out of my recent flags, *one* out of the many had been declined by a moderator (as "no evidence"). The most recent five *pages* of my flags history show *three* declined flags in total.

I'm not asking why the flag was declined; that's beside the point. I do wonder if it's really reasonable to show the warning based on a single declined flag out of a fairly large number of recent flags, all but this one of which were either found helpful or are still pending.

Is the warning a bit overzealous?

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate because you were in the exact same boat. Until about 15 minutes ago, you had exactly 10 flags which had been handled in the past 7 days, 1 of which got declined. So you met the 10% criteria. You shouldn't be seeing the warning anymore now, though.

Comment: @animuson Yeah, that looks right. Also explains why I couldn't reproduce it for a screenshot for the MSE question. How about tweaking that percentage to, say, >10% declined rather than >=10% declined? :-) (Even numbers tend to lend themselves well to edge cases like this...)

Comment: Better to be warned one time too much than one time too little.